# How to Remove Glow Effect from Flutter Slider Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, flutter-slider

With a Slider widget in Flutter, there is a glow effect that radiates from the "thumb" (selection dot) when touch down is active (when user is using the slider):

[image]

This is a "material behavior" that I would like to disable for a more flat design.

Is there a way to remove this in some way, preferably via an argument to the slider?

I noticed that the glow color comes from the "activeColor" argument, but if you change it to transparent, it also affects the "active" section of the slider which is unusable:

[image]

I would like to avoid re-writing my own slider just for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change a single `Slider`, use a `SliderTheme` widget to change the `overlayColor` to transparent.

```
SliderTheme(
  data: SliderThemeData(
    overlayColor: Colors.transparent, // <- disable "glow effect"
  ),
  child: Slider(
    value: _value,
    onChanged: (v) => setState(() => _value = v),
  ),
)
```

To change all `Slider`s in the app, you can modify it at `Theme` level, for example:

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    sliderTheme: SliderThemeData(
      overlayColor: Colors.transparent, // <- disable "glow effect"
    ),
  ),
  home: const MyHomePage(),
);
```

EDIT from OP:

It is apparently also important (maybe a bug as of Flutter 3.3.10) that if you have customized the activeColor argument your slider, you must instead set it using the activeTrackColor argument of *the slider theme* (*not* as an argument to the slider), otherwise the overlayColor set in the theme will have no effect.